# add/remove classes in android OS in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am using phone-gap(1.3) for android app development.
How to add/remove classes in android OS in javascript. I tried this:

```
document.getElementById('delete_a').classList.add('whiteButton');
document.getElementById('delete_a').classList.remove('redButton');
```

But it is not working. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: can u use jquery? U can use .addClassName('b') if so.

Comment: no i want to use javascript only

Answer (score 0):

did you try this:

```
document.getElementById('delete_a').className = "whiteButton";
```

refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Comment: Can you give a little bit more explanation so the link isn't needed?  If the link becomes old it might be difficult to understand your answer.